# Qt QWindow Raster Graphics won't automatically render

Tags: c++, qt

I subclassed QWindow is order to provide simple raster graphics to display incoming frames of a game. I'm following the raster window example located here http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtgui-rasterwindow-example.html.

Almost everything works great except, new frames are only drawn on the screen when the window resizes. I tried running the renderNow() function from my main function, but the window doesn't render new frames because isExposed() is always false. What would be the cause of this?

Here's a link to the code http://pastebin.com/3gxBee7K

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. I create a bool called `mRunning`, and I create a `setRun(bool run)` function.

The function looks like this:

```
void RasterWindow::setRun(bool run) {
    mRunning = run;
    if (run)
        renderLater();
}
```

Then at the end of the `renderNow()` function I added:

```
if (mRunning)
    renderLater();
```